# Spivak: Why does $(f(x))^2=\int_0^x f(t)\frac{t}{1+t^2}dt$ imply that $f^2$ is differentiable?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, proof-explanation, logarithms

Here is a problem from Ch. 18 of Spivak's *Calculus*

> 27. Find all continuous functions $f$ which satisfy the equation
>
> $$(f(x))^2=\int_0^x f(t)\frac{t}{1+t^2}dt$$

The solution manual starts by saying

> The given equation implies that $f^2$ is differentiable, so $f$ is
> differentiable at any $x$ with $f(x)\neq 0$

Why is it implied that $f^2$ is differentiable?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of calculus tells you the integral of a continuous function is differentiable.

The product of continuous functions is continuous, so your integrand is continuous.